# Netty - relationship between NioWorker pool and worker thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

The context is Netty 3.5.x.

What is the relationship between the number of `NioWorker`s and the number of the threads in the worker thread pool when an `NioServerSocketChannelFactory` or `NioClientSocketChannelFactory` is created? Does the design of Netty dictate that there should be at least as many threads available in the threadpool as the number of `NioWorkers`? What happens if you have a fewer number of threads in the thread-pool than the number of `NioWorker`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the relationship is 1:1. So you need to have at least as many threads as NioWorkers. If you have less it will throw an Exception of just "hang" when creating the *SocketChannelFactory, depending on the Executor implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  In my experience, if you have fewer threads in the threadpool than the number of `NioWorker`s, the client or the server sometimes fails to complete connection requests for a long time (internally, the registration task submitted by a boss thread seems to never get picked up).  I wonder if it would make sense for Netty to not allow creations of `ChannelFactory` objects where the maximum number of threads in the thread pool is smaller than the number of `NioWorker`s.

Comment: Currently, it's really easy to make this mistake if you use the constructor that just takes in 2 executors (e.g. `NioClientSocketChannelFactory(Executor, Executor)` -- by default Netty will create twice the number of `NioWorker`s as the number of processors and if the worker executor is unable to provide at least that many threads, you get intermittent connection failures.  Also, if the association is really 1:1, that's probably something worth making explicit in the JavaDoc.